# REst GET Vs POST with big message body

Tags: http, rest, architecture, http-post, http-get

I have a situation where I am grappling with REst GET and POST architecture philosophies in the real world.

I have a REst call that is idempotent in it's nature. It requires a complex data type in it's payload (an insurance policy in XML), does complex business logic on it and returns a premium. It does nothing on the state and so is essentially idempotent.

The REst call is a POST at present. The valid justification to this is that the message body is big and is likely to get dropped and get messy with internet explorer. However, it is also idempotent and violates GET Vs POST fundamentally.

Anyone faced this conundrum before? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem and my solution is pragmatic. My API uses POST even for idempotent when facing the GET request limitations, so:

```
If the form data would contain non-ASCII characters or;
If the form data set is large.
```

I think there are other exceptions, but I can't think one right now.

UPDATE: one more exception, if, for some reason, I don't want a parameter to be visible in the request url I also use POST for idempotent.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if the implication is reversible:

`GET SHOULD be idempotent` is what's defined, but nothing forbids `POST` to be idempotent.

In your place, I'd go for the `POST` method. Plus, if your request contains an entity, it cannot be a `GET`

Answer (score 1):

While I do not think that there is a good alternative to using POST requests for large body GETs, you should keep in mind that POST requests are usually not cached by (reverse) proxies. Most HTTP caches (that I am aware of) don't take the POST body into consideration for computing an objects cache key. This may be a problem if your computation is resource intensive.